# File not found on WebPart Deployment

Tags: web-part, deployment, gac

I followed the Instructions on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261736.aspx) and also this one [here](http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/12/15/developing-web-parts-for-sharepoint-2010/) but unfortunately nothing seems to work.

I've built a custom WebPart and packaged it into a .wsp file since i'm trying to import this WebPart onto another SharePoint instance i'm always getting "File not found" error on calling the site containing the WebPart.

I added the .wsp via `Add-SPSolution` and installed it with `Install-SPSolution`. I want to use it both on the regular SharePoint and the mysites. Since we have two different URLs for the standard SharePoint and mysites I deployed it on both.

After adding it to the GAC i made the safecontrols entry in the web.config file.

I can't find anymore hints or steps that i could have missed during the deployment..

web.config entry:
`<SafeControl Assembly="Beraterprofil, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a1202f7ace683fb7" Namespace="Beraterprofil.VisualWebPart1" TypeName="*" Safe="True"/>`

I suppose the SP-Server can't find the .dll but i can't figure out why...

my references:
`using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles;
using Microsoft.Office.Server;`

Comment: Check the ULS Trace logs for any errors, and then report back.

Comment: Here is a log view.. if i'm reading it right there seem to be existing references to my local sharepoint instance "http://itm-ps"

http://pastebin.com/W2qPyKSM

i first figured there might be some wrong informations in the manifest.xml or sth. like that but then i realized that i had the Server hardcoded in my webpart.. this should be helpful!

any idea how it's possible to figure this out dynamically?

using (SPSite site = new SPSite("https://mysitesstage.itm-consulting.de"))

big thanks though!

Comment: Use the SPContext.Current.Site to get the current site collection

Comment: Do you have a code sample you can provide?

Comment: Side bar: Rather than having to manually add a safe controls entry (especially when you have multiple web front ends that you'd have to manually update), add a safe control entry within your solution. That way, when you deploy your WSP, SharePoint will handle adding the safe controls element to every WFE web.config. I have a blog post here (http://wp.me/p17id5-1op) (it's a wordpress shortened URL) that talks about another topic, but scroll down to the heading that says 'Empty SharePoint Element'. It shows you how to add one.